# Finding the standard deviation of a random variable given by table

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

Call $X$ the claim amount. Im confused as the wording of the problem. Do we need to find the standard deviation of each territory or alltogehter? That is, first find for territory 1,

$$ E(X) = 100 \cdot 0.9 + 500 \cdot 0.08 + 1000 \cdot 0.02 = 150 $$

and

similarly for $E(X^2)$. do we need to find for each territory and then add the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain you for territory $1$

$$E(x)=E\ x_i\cdot P(x_i)=150$$
$$E(x^2)=E\ x_i^2\cdot P(x_i)=49000$$
$$v(x)=E(x^2)-[E(x)]^2$$
$$=49,000-(150)^2$$
$$=49,000-22,500$$
$$v(x)=26,500$$
$$\sqrt{v(x)}=\sqrt{26,500}$$
$$S.D=162.79$$
Similarly, you can do $2$ and $3$